# SELECT FROM a database named from a value in a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a SQL statement that has to pull information from two databases, one is a constant and known database, and the other is dynamically found in the first database.  The databases structure looks like this:

- (database) lookup

  - (table) test

    - (fields) key, database_name
    - (row sample) "foo", "database_foo"
- (database) database_foo

  - (table) bar

    - (fields) important1, important2
    - (row sample) "silly", "test"

So my SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
  test.key as key,
  test.database_name as database_name,
  bar.important1 as important1,
  bar.importnat2 as important2,
FROM
  lookup.test as test,
  (database_name).bar as bar,  # this, obviously, doesn't work
WHERE
  key = 'foo'
LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way I can make this work, or is it better for me to just do two separate SQL statements, one for the lookup, and one for the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **must** do it this way then you need to use dynamic sql **and** a two statements.

You have your query built as a string and then you run an `EXEC` on the query once it's constructed.

In this case you would have a string variable for the db name, then you would create a query from this variable and your literal query, then you would simply execute it.

Be aware, though, this makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection if you don't control the input parameters.

Erland Sommarskog has a great primer on using dynamic SQL:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

**EDIT:** From @BryanMoyle comment below, you will likely need to do both a separate query **and** dynamic sql. You need to extract the value in order to determine the other DB name... Since you cannot use the DB name as a variable otherwise, you'll need to `SELECT` this information first, then stick it into the subsequent query.

Comment: I was writing up a comment about this, and then realized that this won't work for him because the dynamic value being constructed is being extracted from the join, it's not known previously

Comment: @BryanMoyles he shall have to do **both** then, a separate query to lookup the value he needs *and* dynamic sql to change the DB name in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I personally go for 2 separate statements; it would make it easier to control for errors such as the the lookup provides a row, that the row provides a valid database, etc.

As Matthew pointed out, beware of SQLIA and sanitize all user input. I like to MD5 hash inputs and compare to the hash of the value looked up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for two separate queries, mediated by php: It's simpler, more robust, and will keep you sane and productive. Write one query to find out which database you should be talking to. Use php (not SQL) to direct your query to that database:

```
$row = $lookup->prepare("SELECT database_name WHERE key = 'foo'")->execute()->fetch();
$db = $row[0];
```

Then you contact `$db` and ask for the row with key `foo`. Use PHP code to select the right open connection, or switch databases inside the connection with `USE`:

```
$query2 = "USE " . $db . "; SELECT * FROM bar where key == 'foo'"
```